# How to input and compare a string

Tags: c

I'm new to C and I need help.
This code doesn't work, even if I type London into the input I recieve the message from else: "Try again".

```
int main()
{
    char capitalCity;

    scanf("%s", &capitalCity);


    if (capitalCity == 'London'){
        printf("Is the capital city of UK.");
    }
    else{
        printf("Try again.");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: One `char`is not enough, you need an array: `char capitalCity[128];` and then `scanf("%s", capitalCity);` (the array decays into a pointer so you don't need the address of operator `&`), and use `strcmp` instead of `==` to compare strings: `if (strcmp(capitalCity, "London")) {`

Comment: if (strcmp(capitalCity, "London")){
        printf("Is the capital city of UK.");
    }

Comment: still doesn't work

Comment: `scanf` is a quite complex and involved function. In your (corrected) example if you were using the city name `New York` the code would have read `New` and ignored the rest, and no match found. Reading the man pages is essential, even if eye-watering. The concise example on the [MSVC man page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9y6s16x1.aspx) imparts a lot of information about the function.

Comment: Change the title into something sensible. I am tempted to downvote just because of it.

Comment: what's your latest code that doesn't work?

Comment: But, the code i wrote into the comments doesn't work. It still outputs "Try again".

Comment: Did you read the man page yet? If not, do that very next thing.

Comment: So few lines, so many errors. Why don't you take compiler warnings seriously? No offence, but please get a C book and work through the chapters one by one. Don't skip a chapter. All issues should be explained in the book.

Comment: Please do not replace the original code with another flawed version, it will make the comments impossible to follow.

Comment: Rolled back. This is no life-editing site!

Comment: You should also read the man page for all the functions you intend to use. The first comment's use of `strcmp` is incorrect.

Comment: I edited the post, this is how my code looks right now.

Comment: **Will you _please_ stop editing the question text?**

Comment: @GáborBakos: The code has other problems. OP needs to **understand** the problems, not just apply a pattern. That makes things even worse.

Comment: Your if  (capitalCity == 'London'){ } covers only the situation that the input is London what if the user inserted london / LONDON ? in that case the if statement will be false.

Answer (score 1):

There is no `string` data type in C programming language. `Strings` in C are represented as array of characters.

In C, `char` is a data type to represent a character (**char** in C represents the character type, suitable for storing a simple character—traditionally one from the ASCII encoding.). So, all you need to do is declare a array of char data type to represent a `string` in C. Each element in that array will hold a character of your string.

Also, operators in C like ==, !=, +=, + are defined for build-in data types in C and since, there is no operator overloading in C, you can't use these operators with your C-String as C-Strings are not build-in data type in C programming language.

Note: C-Strings are actually Null-terminated array of char data types. That means, last character in any C-String in C will be used to store a Null Character ('\0') which marks the end of the string.

The Header file  has predefined functions that you can use to operate on C-String(Null-terminated array of char data type). You can read more about it over here.

So, your program should look like:

```
#define MAX_CSTR_LEN 100
int main()
{
    char capitalCity[MAX_CSTR_LEN + 1]; ///An extra position to store Null Character if 100 characters are to be stored in it.

    scanf("%s", capitalCity);


    // Use strcmp to compare values of two strings.
    // If strcmp returns zero, the strings are identical
    if (strcmp(capitalCity, "London") == 0) { 
        printf("Is the capital city of UK.");
    }
    else {
        printf("Try again.");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Also, you have to use single quotes for character literals and double quotes for strings in C.

Answer (score -1):

First, there are many things you need to learn. I'm trying my best to explain it to you.

In case of string as input, you can't compare by using `==` operator. you need to use `strcmp()` function which is declared in `<string.h>` header file, it compares character by character and return `0` if both string equal else a non-zero value.

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <string.h> //for strcmp function
#define SIZE 30   //max size buffer for input

int main(){
    char capitalCity[SIZE];
    scanf("%s", capitalCity);
    if(strcmp(capitalCity, "London") == 0){ //if(capitalCity == 'London') won't work in case of string comparison 
        printf("Is the capital city of UK.");
    } else{
        printf("Try again.");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

further reading http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/c/

Comment: Not my DV, but `scanf("%s", &capitalCity);` --> `scanf("%s", capitalCity);`

Comment: @WeatherVane my mistake. corrected.